# Why does the innerContainer not fill outer container?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a writing area and a message area, I get my container on the current height of the window, but when I try to split up the container into two parts the inner container does not fill up the outer container.

Question: How do I get the `#message` element fit the `#chatContainer` minus the `#writingBox` height?

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    color: #393939;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#chatContainer {
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: calc(100% - 54px);
    padding: 54px 0 0 0;
    background: lightgray;
}

#messages {
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: calc(100% - 54px);
    background: lightgreen;
}

#writingBox {
    border-top: 1px solid #393939;
    height: 54px;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatContainer">
  <div id="messages"></div>
  <div id="writingBox">
    <div id="newMessage">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you cannot set a height if the parent container only has a min-height set on it.

You can use flexbox to achieve what you want:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #393939;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#chatContainer {
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 54px 0 0 0;
  background: lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#writingBox {
  border-top: 1px solid #393939;
  height: 54px;
  background: lightblue;
}

#messages {
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  background: lightgreen;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatContainer">
  <div id="messages"></div>
  <div id="writingBox">
    <div id="newMessage">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i did not know this. Nice solution with display flex, 
I was always afraid  of the `flex` attribute.

Comment: Wow, it even works with a outer div to display it. [JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7oreb9ud/)!

Comment: it's quite nice and easy to use.  Here are a couple of useful links: [playground](http://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/adLPwv), [flex guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks :-) I will take a look, and thanks for editing my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height for your #chatContainer to be calc(100% - 55px) and the height for #messages to be calc(100% - 55px)

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    color: #393939;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#chatContainer {
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    height: calc(100% - 55px);
    min-height: calc(100% - 55px);
    padding: 54px 0 0 0;
    background: lightgray;
}

#messages {
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    height: calc(100% - 55px);
    background: lightgreen;
}

#writingBox {
    border-top: 1px solid #393939;
    height: 54px;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatContainer">
  <div id="messages"></div>
  <div id="writingBox">
    <div id="newMessage">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You nearly got it, but i need to scroll to see the writingBox, which should allways be visible.

Comment: I updated the answer, you have to set the height for #chatContainer to be also calc(100% - 54px)

Comment: Update it to -55px for the border :-) Upvote incomming

Answer (score 0):

change `100%` to `100vh` in `min-height`.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    color: #393939;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#chatContainer {
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 54px);
    padding: 54px 0 0 0;
    background: lightgray;
}

#messages {
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 108px);
    background: lightgreen;
}

#writingBox {
    border-top: 1px solid #393939;
    height: 54px;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatContainer">
  <div id="messages"></div>
  <div id="writingBox">
    <div id="newMessage">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not think about setting the containers to full viewheight, maybe it will get displayed in another div. This approach does not work for me.